# juju bootstrap environment: Failed to connect to streams.canonical.com port 443: Connection refused

Tags: juju, maas

I've created a new virtual lab on KVM to test the last release of Juju Gui.

In this environment I've created:

- a VM for MaaS and with 2 network interface (one for public (NAT) and one for private (isolated);
- a VM to deploy Juju Gui.

on Maas Server the network interface are so configurated

> ```
>     auto eth0 
>     iface eth0 inet static
>     address 1.1.100.10
>     netmask 255.255.255.0
>     network 1.1.100.0
>     broadcast 1.1.100.255
>     gateway 1.1.100.1
>     # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
>     dns-nameservers 1.1.100.1
>     #dns-search maas
>
>     auto eth1 
>     iface eth1 inet static
>     address 1.1.101.10
>     netmask 255.255.255.0
>     network 1.1.101.0
>     broadcast 1.1.101.255
>     gateway 1.1.101.1
>     # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
>     #dns-nameservers 1.1.101.1
>     #dns-search maas
> ```

while on virt-manager both Virtual Net are so set

[image]

[image]

on Maas UI

[image]

the network

[image]

But while I try to make the bootstrap of the environment using the following command:

> `$: sudo juju bootstrap -e maas --to JujuGui.maas --debug`

at the end of the procedure receive that error

[image]

if I tried to run this

$: wget https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.25.3-trusty-amd64.tgz

the download started without problem

[image]

While on Maas the node result deployed

[image]

I've also try nslookup, dig and ping commands for that url and all commands gave me right result.

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that changed the vNet Private on Virtual Networks of virt-manager from Isolated to Forwarding

[image]

Certainly that one is not a right solution, but at moment it's only solution I've found.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using the forwarding NAT Network but it can not fix the issue.
The vm doesn't have internet access. That is why it is stuck at the downloading steps and make whole bootstrap failed.

Here I follow other's solution and test in my lab env. It works fine:

1. `mkdir ~./.juju/sync-tools`
2. set `sync-tool` destination folder.

   - If maas 1.8 version:

     ```
     sudo juju sync-tools -e maas --destination="/home/xxx/.juju/sync-tools/"
     ```
   - If maas 1.9 version:

     ```
     sudo juju sync-tools -e maas --local-dir="/home/xxx/.juju/sync-tools/"
     ```

Here is the bootstrap command:

```
~/.juju$ juju bootstrap --upload-tools=true --metadata-source="/home/xxx/.juju/sync-tools"  --to bootstrap-node.maas --debug
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to specify a proxy for https? You got a connection refused error, but the service is up on Canonical's end.

Comment: the network is configured as showed above, if I try to do a ping to google.co.uk the result is right for me the navigation to external is working

Comment: using this command $: juju bootstrap -e maas --to JujuGui.maas  --upload-tools --debug the result has been right look the log http://paste.ubuntu.com/14696174/

Comment: and if try to deploy juju-gui obtain this error: "juju deploy juju-gui --to 0
ERROR cannot retrieve charm "cs:trusty/juju-gui-48": cannot get archive: Get https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v4/trusty/juju-gui-48/archive: dial tcp 162.213.33.122:443: connection refused"

Comment: --upload-tools bypasses the download of the tools tarball, that's why you don't get the error. I think you have a network egress restriction at your site that prevents you from accessing port 443/TCP directly. The fact that navigation works (have you tried https?) could just indicate that your browser is already configured to use a proxy.

Comment: I've upgraded the post

Comment: Interesting, I also had a 503 error today, and it was because the maas-proxy service (squid3) was for some reason using ipv6 to fetch files from archive.ubuntu.com. Can you check if that's the case in the proxy log files on the maas server, at /var/log/maas/proxy/access.log ?

Comment: Today I've try to set up all environment and there isn't the "503 error" any more, but the "Failed to connect to streams.canonical.com port 443: Connection refused" is still there, when I try to deploy juju-gui

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. Something in your networking setup is preventing that machine from reaching out to streams.canonical.com on port 443/tcp.